# Inserting a single element in a linked list gives a segmentation fault - C++

Tags: c++

The below code intends to perform insertion of a single element in a linked list and then print it. Although, I am getting a segmentation fault while printing the value in main function. Could you please help me identify what is wrong with it ?

I have tried to print the value of data in the insert function and it works fine which means the creation of new node and assignment of the value to it is working fine.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

//insert a new node
Node* insertNode(int data,Node* head)
{
    Node* cNode = head;
   if (!head)
   {
       head = new Node;
       head->data = data;
       head->next = NULL;
   }
   else
   {
       while(cNode->next)
       {
           cNode = cNode->next;
       }
       cNode->next = new Node;
       cNode->next->data = data;
       cNode->next->next = NULL;
   }
   return head;
}

// print a list
void print(Node* head)
{
    /*while(head->next)
    {
        cout << head->data << " ";
        head = head->next;
    }*/
    cout << "printing data" << endl;
    cout << "data : " << head->data;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "inside main" << endl;
    Node* aNode = NULL;
    insertNode(2,aNode);
    print(aNode);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the print function to print the value of data for the single node that I created .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `head` parameter in `insertNode` function should be a reference (or a pointer to pointer to Node). Beacause in the current form, it is an input parameter, but you need to be in-out parameter. It means that in the current code, your `aNode` variable is NULL and is always stays NULL.

I recommend this:
`void insertNode(int data, Node &head)`

Then you create an object in `main` this way: `Node aNode;`

It will allow you to update the existing variable directly and you don't need a return value. Also, this way it will be a little bit more C++like, your original code is more like a plain C code.

Or if you want to write it in plain C:
`void insertNode(int data, Node **head)`

Then you change the call from `main`: `insertNode(2, &aNode);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Isn't the `head` parameter updated to point to the address of the newly created node for first node being created ? Since the node is being created with the usage of `new` , I was hoping that `head` will still be able to point to the correct address once the flow returns from `insertNode` .

Pardon me for anything I am missing here . Just starting out with pointers .

Comment: You create `new Node` and store it in `cNode`. It is a local variable, it lives only inside that function. But you never update `aNode`, it stays null.

Comment: I got it working. Like you mentioned , the `insertNode` function needed to accept the argument as a reference or as a pointer to pointer to Node.

I had to change `insertNode(int data, Node* head)` to `insertNode(int data,Node* &head)`. The earlier version was indeed working on its own copy of `head` .

Thanks again for your inputs.